# Access add more than one record at a time using subform

Tags: ms-access, record, subform

[image]

Hello, so I need some help. The image attached is the form I'm working on. I got it working up until the point I can save that record and go back to my query where training records are and see it in there. The save button does not clear any info out of the form, but if I do change the id of 345 to say 346, it won't make a new line. It just rewrites over the 345 in the record.  However, what I fully intend to do is have this store multiple records at once and the subform is where you can see what you're going to add once you hit save. This is my first big project, so speak in noob terms. Thanks!

Comment: Show code! Go back to query?? Don't show queries, use Forms bound to them! The query contains multiple records you want to add (show data as [text-table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables))? ID is an autonumber? Should be read only and not visible!

Comment: Enter new data on NewRecord row. Record is committed to table when: 1) close table/query/form; 2) move to another record; 3) run code to save. ID is autonumber in subform - you can't change this number. Why does main form show same ID number as subform? This is a design issue, not programming, and therefore question not suitable for SO.

Comment: Are you trying to emulate a Split form design?

Comment: Simply add a `command button` to add new record. Then hit on that command button to go to new record which will clear previous save data. Means will go to new empty record.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do and I'll use an example of a customer with multiple orders to explain how to use a subform to add multiple orders to the same person.

First, you want to have the Customer_ID and then a Product_ID. In the Product_ID table, make sure you have a field called "Customer_ID" which will act as the foreign key that will reference the Customer_ID field in the Customer table. When you add a subform to the Customer form, you set the "Master Field" and "Child Field" to the "Customer_ID". This will allow the subform to reference the Customer_ID field and maintain the relationship and a unique Product_ID (not Customer_ID) will be generated each time you add a record to the subform.

Select the subform and go to "Property Sheet>Data" and double-check the link in the master and child field.

Comment: I think you know what I'm trying to do. I messed this a little but I'm a bit confused yet... I think I might just be getting the relationships and master/childs fields mixed. This is currently what I have for my table structures:

Comment: @ aquadratic Employee Table - emp_id (pk); Standards List Table - st_no_id (pk); and an association Employee Records Table - tr_no (pk), st_no_id (fk), emp_id (fk). tr_no is training records number which is an autonumber that makes each employee record unique. Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: what's the relationship type between the Employee Table and Standards List Table? one to many?

Comment: the relationship is many to many so I have an association table in the middle that allows it to be a one to many. The middle table is employee records where I have emp_id (FK) and st_no_id (FK) and table_record_no as Primary key

Answer (score 0):

Simple 1-to-many Employee-Task relationship

[image: Simple Employee-Task relationship]

How the relationship should look like with the Subform

[image: How the relationship should look like with the Subform]

What the main form and subform should look like. You can do something similar with the Standard List Table based on the relationship you've established.

[image: What the main form and subform should look like. You can do something similar with the Standard List Table based on the relationship you've established]